# array_chunk in Javascript, after Appending a big chunk using ForLoop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**(In edit part at the bottom, I have included my code that I got closest)**

---

Explanation:
I have an ajax post, which fetches data from controller. On success, I have a for loop for each post:

```
success: function(data) {
     var posts = data['data'];
     var postsCount = data['per_page'];
     var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

     for(i=0; i < postsCount; i++){
         frag.appendChild(postElem(posts));
     }
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(frag);
}
```

I also have another function `function postElement()` which creates `eachPost` div, appends the child divs into `eachPost` and returns it

```
function postElem(posts){
   var eachPost = document.createElement('div');
   eachPost.className = "col-md-4 eachPost";

       //and a big chunk of code that finally appends into `eachPost`.

  return eachPost;
}
```

This works perfectly until here

The structure I got working in html, and also want to achieve in javascript looks like this:

```
<div id="content">
   @foreach (array_chunk($posts->all(), 3) as $row)
      <div class="row eachRow">
         @foreach($row as $post)
            <div class="col-md-3 eachPost">
                   <!-- rest of the code -->
```

After some research, I figured out I can achieve `array_chunk` like this:

```
var n,j,tempArray,chunk = 3;
for (n=0,j=posts.length; n<j; n+=chunk) {
   tempArray = posts.slice(n,n+chunk);

      // my other `for`.

}
```

However, whatever I tried, I couldn't figure out how I can achieve what I achieved in html. I couldn't import `eachRow` bit in javascript. What is the way of doing it? Is it because of the `document.createDocumentFragment()` bit?

---

**Edit: What I tried, that fails what I want to achieve:**

```
success: function(data) {
     var posts = data['data'];
     var postsCount = data['per_page'];
     var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
     var eachRow = document.createDocumentFragment();
     var n,j,tempArray,chunk = 3;

        for (n=0,j=posts.length; n<j; n+=chunk) {
            tempArray = posts.slice(n,n+chunk); 

             for(i=0; i < tempArray.length; i++){
                 frag.appendChild(postElem(tempArray));
             }

            var eachRow = document.createElement('div');
            eachRow.className = "row eachRow";
            eachRow.appendChild(frag);
         }
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(eachRow);
}
```

In this part, it appends the stuff in `frag`. It creates a div. (See bottom for the view:source)

This creates a post inside each row, and it's like a straight line of posts, instead of 3 posts in 1 row.

- *What I want to achieve*

  ```
  <div class="row eachRow">
     <div class="eachPost>_</div>
     <div class="eachPost>_</div>
     <div class="eachPost>_</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row eachRow">
     <div class="eachPost>_</div>
     <div class="eachPost>_</div>
     <div class="eachPost>_</div>
  </div>
  ```
- *The code at the top is producing:*

  ```
  <div class="row eachRow">_</div>     
  <div class="row eachRow">_</div>
    <!-- for each bit -->
  <div class="eachPost>_</div>
  <div class="eachPost>_</div>
  <div class="eachPost>_</div>
  ```
- *Code in edit part is producing:*

  ```
  <div class="row eachRow">
     <div class="eachPost>_</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row eachRow">
     <div class="eachPost>_</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row eachRow">
     <div class="eachPost>_</div> 
  </div>
  ```

Comment: `tempArray.count` should be `tempArray.length`. Should be getting error thrown on that line

Comment: I fixed my code at the bottom. It just got it wrong while importing the code in question. I also added a description at the bottom, too.

Comment: This question could be answerable if you included the HTML that your code is producing, and an example of the code you want it to produce.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I added that bit too. Also minor tweak added.

Comment: One thing that's a bit confusing; you pass an array of of three elements (`tempArray`) to `postElem`, but only one `eachPost` comes out. Does `postElem` take a single post or many?

Comment: Before I added `array_chunk` method, it was creating one for each one (top code is producing bit). However, I couldn't figure out how do it after I use `array_chunk` for loop

Comment: So do you mean I should put a 3rd for loop inside `postElem()` that sees the counts `n` inside `postElem`? I got really confused here